# Call a sequence through a function in PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql

I have a sequence in the database, and I wanted to call the sequence through a function.
I have tried below, need an assistance to create the function in a standard process, as this is not working.

```
select nextval('code_seq')
```

```
CREATE FUNCTION code_sequence(integer) RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE SQL
    IMMUTABLE
    return select nextval('code_seq');
```

Comment: WHY? Neither your input param, nor the volatility `IMMUTABLE`, nor the function itself make any sense. Just use `nextval('code_seq')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION local_accounts_sequence(integer) RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE SQL
    IMMUTABLE
    RETURN (select nextval('code_seq'));
    
select local_accounts_sequence(1)
```

[image]
check out this solution

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
CREATE FUNCTION local_accounts_sequence() RETURNS integer   
    AS 'SELECT nextval(''code_seq'');'
    LANGUAGE SQL;
```

call it like this :

```
select local_accounts_sequence();
```

Comment: This function is definitely not immutable, it does change the database, it changes the sequence. It's a VOLATILE function. RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT is also rather strange for a function without any input at all.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve using below statements,

```
CREATE FUNCTION code_sequence(out seq int) 
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    as $$ 
    begin
    select nextval('code_seq') into seq;
end;$$
```